# getting 404 not found error on vercel, while deploying my nodejs code

Tags: node.js, express, deployment, vercel

[image]I'm encountering a 404 Not Found error on Vercel when attempting to deploy my Node.js code. Here's a breakdown of my setup and the steps I've taken:

- I have a Node.js application that I'm trying to deploy on Vercel.
- I've configured my deployment settings and attempted to deploy through Vercel's platform.
- However, during the deployment process, I'm consistently getting a 404 Not Found error.

I've checked the following aspects:

1. Request Body: Ensured that my request to Vercel includes all necessary data and is properly formatted.
2. Request Formatting: Verified that the request follows the expected format and includes all required fields.
3. Authorization: Confirmed that I have proper authorization credentials for deploying to Vercel.
4. Endpoint URL: Checked that I'm sending the request to the correct endpoint URL for Vercel.
5. Server-side Code: Reviewed my Node.js code for any issues related to handling incoming requests and deployment.
6. Network Connectivity: Ensured there are no issues with my network connection preventing the request from reaching Vercel's servers.

Despite these checks, I'm still facing the 404 error. Could someone provide insights into potential reasons for this error and how to troubleshoot it effectively? Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image: 404 error found]